# CRM 2016 Reports require log in when clicking on a link

Tags: reporting-services, outlook, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

We use a number of update reports that reference phone call activities amongst other data. One field that is shown in the report is the subject line of the Phone Call which automatically creates a hyper link to the Phone Call being referenced.

When the report is run using the web interface, regardless of browser, the link opens the Phone Call without an issue. However when opened from the Outlook plugin a new browser window is opened and the user is required to log in, which can make working through a report tedious.

I am aware that one solution would be to always run reports from a browser, or leaving the new browser window opened by Outlook open, as any subsequent links  are opened in the same browser which is already "logged in". However, is there a way to remove the requirement for the first log in entirely? Could the link created in the Report have to log in credentials embedded so to speak?

Comment: I believe that the only way of handling that is configuring Single Sign On for your organization (so that users will not have to login to CRM after they logged in on their working stations.

Comment: They could use the browser instead of Outlook to interact with CRM (this is always a good idea regardless of what they need), or keep a browser window open and logged in so it only asks them to re-login sometimes (O365 does that as a security measure)